# toggle back to original color with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Using jQuery library to make a fade in div.
How do I toggle back to the original colors ?(`background-color:blue and color:white`)

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#galleryb").click(function(){
            $(".panel").fadeToggle(500);
            $("#galleryb").css("background-color","#fff");
            $("#galleryb").css("color","#000");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".galleryb").click(function(){
$(".panel").fadeToggle(500);
$('.galleryb').toggleClass('cls_name');
});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

this is what **css classes** are for.

instead of manipulating inline styles via javascript/jQuery, try:

css:

```
.cls_name{background:red;color:blue;}
```

jquery:

```
$('#element').addClass('cls_name');
```

or

```
$('#element').removeClass('cls_name');
```

or

```
$('#element').toggleClass('cls_name');
```

hope that helps.

Comment: im pretty green at this. I understand what you're say but I can't put it to code.
Do you have a solution that will manipulate inline style?

Comment: actually no. I need an inline solution. I can't override the `color`

Comment: don't assign it with js in the first place, use ONLY css classes.

Comment: I have to with an <a> link

Comment: you can write css class for that: `a{color:#000;}` and `a.color{color:red;}`

Comment: it will have black text, and when you'll add the class 'color' it will have the color red.

Comment: Is it me, or this answer is answering the question in a CSS way, but the question isn't tagged CSS! You need to change the colors using js :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

### First way:

You can save the current CSS properties by using:

```
$('selector').css('background-color');
```

And save them as a variable, then when you want to change them back, use the variable and set the value as:

```
$('selector').css('background-color', varvalue);
```

### Second way,

If you know what value you're going to change them back into, then you can try using the simple jQuery way like you did first:

```
$("#galleryb").css("background-color","blue");
$("#galleryb").css("color","white");
```

And you'll get the result!

First way is better if you don't know the css properties of some element, and want to change it back to its real value. Second way is perfect is you know the values you want to change back into.

Answer (score 0):

Reset all (inline) styles:

```
$("#galleryb").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: there aren't any inline styles.

Comment: any .css() style you apply with jQuery is inline ;) (check firebug or chrome console to make sure)